# how to set Context docBase and its path in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring-MVC we use
`<Context docBase="/home/sushil/Audio/resources" path="/project/playfile"/>`
and play all file of resouces directory.

and i am new for Spring Boot, so how to we set it in application.properties file ?

`<Context docBase="/home/sushil/Audio/resources" path="/project/playfile"/>`

how to i above `<Context>` tag convert in Spring-Boot. and i have to need of locating virtual path like `/path/playfile` in my jsp.

Comment: Did you found the answer ?